# JavaScript and square bracket notation

Tags: javascript, object

I am new in Java Script. In both of my books: http://www.larryullman.com/books/modern-javascript-develop-and-design and http://www.packtpub.com/object-oriented-javascript/book
both authors are saying that this notation: `object[unknownYetProperty]` should work when we have object and variable which is objects future property. The problem is two others notation works `object['unknownYetProperty']` and `object.unknownYetProperty` but not first one.

```
var a1 = 'spring';
var a2 = 'autumn';
var a3 = 'summer';

var object = {
    propertyA1 : a1, // according to books this only this should work :-/
    propertyA2 : a2,
    propertyA3 : a3
}

console.log(object[propertyA1] + ' ' + object['propertyA2'] + ' ' + object.propertyA3);
```

The working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/cachaito/p78Le

Could anyone explain it to me?

Comment: There's nothing to explain, it's perfectly normal it isn't working. Notations 2 and 3 are indeed correct

Answer (score 4):

The problem with `object[propertyA1]` is that `propertyA1` does not exist.

Basically, it's like doing the following (which doesn't work either): `alert(propertyA1);`

In contrast with the other two, which correctly reference the fields on your object:

```
object['propertyA2'] === object.propertyA2 === a2 == 'autumn'

object.propertyA3 == a3 == 'summer'
```

This is how it would have worked:

```
var propertyA1 = 'propertyA1',
    temp = object[propertyA1]; // === 'spring'
```

Answer (score 3):

`propertyAl` doesn't exist. The reason the string literal and dot notation work is because you are correctly accessing the properties of the object. In the first one, you are trying to access `object[undefined]` because propertyA1 isn't defined.

Answer (score 1):

The property you are accessing using the array notation should be specified as a string.

```
object['propertyA1']
```

is the right way to access the property of the object.

Whenever you create an object, the left side of the colon symbol is always a string. Hence, when accessing using array notation, strings should be used for properties.

Comment: Thank You all for reply. One I don'y get is why both authors wrote this way to access unknown property :-/

Answer (score 1):

Well, when you write this:

```
object['propertyA1']
```

Javascript tries to find a property called `propertyA1` inside object.

But when you use:

```
object[propertyA1]
```

Javascript tries to find a property inside object called... uh, lets see what's inside `var propertyA1`... WTF? there is no variable with that name!! ok, then propertyA1 is undefined so:

```
object[undefined]
```

The difference is that Javascript knows what 'propertyA1' is (a string xD) but when you remove the quotes, that's not a string, that's a variable you have not declared yet.